# Lambda synchronous invocation with retry

Tags: aws-lambda

Currently I have a lambda (C#) which is reading a dynamo db stream and a try/catch to catch any issues and write directly to a dead letter queue (SQS).

So with an invocation type of synchronous, what is the best way/tool to use to carry out retries within the lambda itself?

After X amount of failed retries - I would then write to SQS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I got your questions right, but if you want to handle Lambda exceptions in a DLQ, [this might help](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html).